# C# List Index Operator doesn't return copy of reference to reference-type

Tags: c#, indexing, reference, return

This is something I can't get my head around. I have the following sample code in C#:

```
class TestProgram
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var scenario = new Scenario(10);

        var persons = scenario.GetPersons();    //returns copy of reference pointing to internal List
        persons[0] = new Person("Modified");    //why does index operator return actual object, and not a copy of the reference to the object, as below?
        Console.WriteLine(scenario.Persons[0].Name);    //internal List was modified
        Console.WriteLine("Point to same object: " + (persons[0] == scenario.Persons[0]));  //both refs point to the same object

        var pppp = scenario.GetP(); //returns copy of the reference pointing to internal object
        pppp = new Person("Modified");  //overwriting copy of reference has no impact on original object, as expected
        Console.WriteLine(scenario.p.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Point to same object: " + (pppp == scenario.p));

        var pppp2 = scenario[0]; //returns copy of the reference pointing to internal object
        pppp2 = new Person("Modified"); //overwriting copy of reference has no impact on original object, as expected
        Console.WriteLine(scenario.p.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Point to same object: " + (pppp2 == scenario.p));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Person(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}

public class Scenario
{
    public Person p = new Person("DDD");

    public Person GetP()
    {
        return p;
    }

    public Person this[int index]
    {
        get { return p; }
    }

    public IList<Person> Persons;

    public Scenario(int nrPersons)
    {
        Persons = new List<Person>(nrPersons);
        for(int i = 0; i < nrPersons; i++)
            Persons.Add(new Person("DDD"));
    }

    public IList<Person> GetPersons()
    {
        return Persons;
    }
}
```

So, my question is why does the index operator of List seem to return the internal object? I was under the impression that a method/overloaded operator, when passing/returning a reference type, will copy and return it by value, by default. Meaning a new reference pointing to the same object should be return. As is the case with the subsequent pppp and pppp2 references, where it behaves as expected.

I've looked with dotpeek over the List implementation, and haven't seen anything revealing. And from what I know being able to return a ref to a reference type will only be supported starting with C# 7.0.

So how does this happen? Am I missing something? Is the compiler doing some trickery to achieve this? Because, I'm not complaining about the behavior. It seems like it's what you'd want to happen in this case. But am just surprised by the inconsistent behavior.

Thanks. And I hope it's not something really trivial that I'm missing.

Comment: In your mind, try replacing `persons[0]` with `persons.Index0` and see if you can see the difference between `persons.Index0 = new Person("Modified");` and `pppp = new Person("Modified");` I think it will become clear.

Comment: yeah, you're overwriting the pointer with a pointer to the new object, not the object itself

Comment: I think it's cleared up now. I don't know why I was under the impression that persons[0] will return (call the get of the indexer) to return a copy which I was expecting to overwrite. But in actuality it's calling the setter of the indexer. And passing in the reference to the new object. Thanks guys! I think I expected it to work like in C++ (if I'm not mistaken, that's how it works there, right?)

Comment: C++ works exactly the same (if you consistently map C# `Person` to C++'s  `Person*`)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: I'm not very experienced in C++, so maybe I'm missing something, but the following code behaves differently to me. the subscript operator returns a reference to the internal object, while in C# nothing was returned to the caller, but was received as a parameter. And now that I see it, I'm confused about something else. I was under the impression that C++ references can't be pointed to other objects, unlike pointers can. So then why can I point the returned reference to the new object in C++ sample below:

Comment: class Person
{
public:
 string name = "DDD";

 string& operator[] (const int index)
 {
  return name;
 }
};


int main()
{
 string n("Modified");
 Person p;
 p[0] = n;
 cout << "Text: " << p.name << endl;

 return 0;
}

Comment: `string&` can't be really represented in C#... Code similar to C# indexer would be `string* operator[](int index){return &name;} ` (and not de-reference on assignment). If you want to see behavior similar to C++ class in C# - use `struct` in C# (also you can't match C++ reference anyway).

Comment: Interesting. I always thought that C++ references were the closest to C# references, since they also act like pointers that don't require dereferencing

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're describing - passing a reference vs. a copy of a reference - is applicable when passing arguments between methods. If you include the `ref` keyword you pass the reference. Otherwise by default it's a copy of the reference.

The purpose of a `List` is to contain a set of references to objects and to be able to maintain that set. So it's to be expected that if you do this:

```
persons[0] = new Person("Modified");
```

You're replacing whatever reference was previously held at the first position in that list with a new reference.

When you do this:

```
var pppp2 = scenario[0];
```

you're creating a variable which holds a reference to an instance of a `Scenario`. You can then update that variable with a different reference (or `null`.)

Really in both cases you're doing the same thing. Think of `persons` as a collection of references, and `persons[0]` is a single reference in that collection. Whether you update your variable (`pppp2`) or your list element (`persons[0]`) you're updating which reference it contains.